# In Azure Function App auth_settings not apply v2 authentication

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create Linux function app with Authentication set to `v2` and for this i am using this provider:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app

For this i created a module:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  name                 = var.name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  location             = var.location
  storage_account_name = var.storage_account_name
  service_plan_id      = var.service_plan_id
  app_settings         = var.app_settings

  auth_settings {
    enabled          = var.auth_settings_enabled
    runtime_version = "~2" // auth v2
    dynamic "active_directory" {
      for_each = auth_settings_enabled ? [1] : []
      content {
        client_id         = var.auth_active_directory.client_id
        client_secret     = var.auth_active_directory.client_secret
        allowed_audiences = var.auth_active_directory.allowed_audiences
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And function declaration:

```
module "function_app" {
  source = "./function-app-module"

  // standard vars like name etc here...

  auth_settings_enabled = true
  auth_active_directory = {
    client_id         = var.clientid
    client_secret     = var.clientsecret
    allowed_audiences = [ var.audience ]
  }
}
```

Output plan from `terraform apply` command looks like this:

```
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9619896Z       [32m+[0m [0mauth_settings {
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9620448Z           [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mallowed_external_redirect_urls[0m[0m = (known after apply)
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9621080Z           [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mdefault_provider[0m[0m               = (known after apply)
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9621641Z           [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0menabled[0m[0m                        = true
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9622161Z           [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mruntime_version[0m[0m                = "~2"
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9622721Z           [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mtoken_refresh_extension_hours[0m[0m  = 72
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9623295Z           [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mtoken_store_enabled[0m[0m            = false
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9623984Z           [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0munauthenticated_client_action[0m[0m  = (known after apply)
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9624219Z 
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9624606Z           [32m+[0m [0mactive_directory {
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9625101Z               [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mallowed_audiences[0m[0m = [
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9625660Z                   [32m+[0m [0m"00000-0000-0000-0000-00000",
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9625962Z                 ]
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9626510Z               [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mclient_id[0m[0m         = "00000-0000-0000-0000-00000"
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9627114Z               [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mclient_secret[0m[0m     = (sensitive value)
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9627435Z             }
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9627654Z         }
2022-10-06T12:14:13.9627743Z
```

And still it is creating `v1` authentication app:
[image]

My question is, what i did wrong and `v2` authenticated app is not created

Answer (score 0):

Use **Microsoft** instead of **Active Directory** like below:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  name                 = var.name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  location             = var.location
  storage_account_name = var.storage_account_name
  service_plan_id      = var.service_plan_id
  app_settings         = var.app_settings

  auth_settings {
    enabled          = var.auth_settings_enabled
    runtime_version = "~2" // auth v2
    dynamic "microsoft" {
      for_each = auth_settings_enabled ? [1] : []
      content {
        client_id         = var.auth_active_directory.client_id
        client_secret     = var.auth_active_directory.client_secret
        oauth_scopes = var.auth_active_directory.allowed_audiences
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***For more information refer:*** [Terraform Azure Linux Function App Microsoft Authentication](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app#microsoft)

Comment: This appears to give the exact same result as above.